# Arduino Automatic Light Switch 2

Tags: automation, arduino

I'm currently working on an automatic light switch. Here's my code:

```
#include <Servo.h>

boolean time = false;
const int timeLim = 10000;
const int delLen = 5000;
int pirVal = 0;

const int pirPin = 2;
const int sensePin = 5;
boolean timeRet = false;
int lightVal;
Servo  myServo;
unsigned long limit;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pirPin, INPUT);
  myServo.attach(11);
  myServo.write(40);

}

void loop() {
  unsigned long Timer = millis(); 

  pirVal = digitalRead(pirPin); 
  int lightVal = analogRead(sensePin);

  Serial.print(pirVal);
  Serial.print(' ');
  Serial.print(lightVal);
  Serial.print(' ');
  Serial.print(Timer);
  Serial.print(' ');
  Serial.print(time);
  Serial.print(' ');
  Serial.print(limit);
  Serial.print(' ');
  Serial.println(timeRet);

  if ( lightVal < 400 ) {
    time = false;
    limit = 0;
    timeRet = false;
  } if ( lightVal < 400 && pirVal == 1 ) {
    unsigned long time = false;
    pirVal = 0;
    myServo.write(160);
  } if ( lightVal > 400 && pirVal == 0 && timeRet == false){
    limit = getTimeLim( timeLim, Timer );
    pirVal = 0;
    timeRet = true;
  } if ( lightVal > 400 && pirVal == 0 && timeRet == true ) {
    time = timeStat ( limit, Timer );
  } if ( lightVal > 400 && time == true ) {
    myServo.write(40);
  }
}

int getTimeLim( const int timeLim, unsigned long Timer ) {
  unsigned long limit = Timer + timeLim;
  return limit;
}

boolean timeStat( unsigned long limit, unsigned long Timer ) {

  if ( Timer < limit ) {
    time = false;
  } else if ( Timer > limit ) {
    time = true;
  }
  return time;
}
```

The problem is that when you look at the serial the first time the getTimeLim function it works, but the second time is always some outrageous number (e.g. 4294937965). I don't know why it would give me this huge number. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your code works now and you want to optimize it, i would suggest this:

```
// ( pseudo code since i'm not familiar with arduino )

void loop( ){

    if( ( analogRead( sensePin ) < 400 ) 
    &&  ( digitalRead( pirPin ) ) ){

        myServo.write( 160 );               // turn on light

        int time_end = millis( ) + 60,000;  // initiate timer value

        while( millis( ) < time_end );      // poll time until at 60s

        myServo.write( 40 );                // turn off light
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason I didn't use else if statements is because whenever I do, the whole code fails and nothing happens at all. Also, unfortunately, it still spits out that huge number

Comment: okay, try explaining to us what your variables are suppose to do so that we can understand it better.

Comment: Actually I saw the last part of your advice, instead of using getTimeLim, just replace it with timeLim + Timer. That solved my problem! Thank you so much.

Comment: Also, can you recommend anything I can do in my code to make it more efficient? i.e best practices or pointing out any redundancies?

Comment: here's the link: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2HBEhxR4-B9dDhrS21ZajFUY0E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: i can't access the link. as for your code, i would wait until there's low light and motion and then enter a new loop that only polls for time. i'll redo my answer